# Delete the formula Expression of particular cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an Excel file, and I want to remove the existing formula on particular cell.

Is it possible to remove formula expresion from a complete column and/or for a particular cell? If so, how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anythong in perticular :) ?

Comment: @Freeman don't know how to get the formulla and then how that will be removed